# Creating storage path for file from first characters of a hash

Tags: php, strings

I made the following function to create the storage path for files from the the first 5 characters of the file's hash:

```
function create_path($hash)
{
  $splitted_hash = str_split(strtolower(substr($hash, 0, 5)));
  $path = "";
  foreach($splitted_hash as $char) {
        $path.="/$char";
  }
  return "$path/";
}
// will output something like "a/h/q/6/d/"
```

But is there a better way to do that? This seems a bit cumbersome.

Comment: s/splitted/split/g

Comment: Please do not edit the question, especially the code, after an answer has been posted. Changing the question may cause answer invalidation. Everyone needs to be able to see what the reviewer was referring to. [What to do after the question has been answered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Oh don't worry, all I edited was the variable name to match with the answer after I also edited the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Php has a `join` (also known as `implode`) so you can simply do

```
function createPath($hash)
{
  return join("/", str_split(strtolower(substr($hash, 0, 5)))) . "/";
}
```

Note the concatenation for the final "/".

Comment: Oh nice, thank you! In my case I prefer to have forward slash at the end because it's a directory so I will just do it in 2 lines (Unless you have a nicer code like the one you wrote above), and do `return "$path/";`

Comment: Can't you concatenate in the return line? My php is rusty, hang on

Comment: See update answer.

Answer (score 3):

## Use consistent spacing, Follow PHP standards for readability

There are recommended standards for PHP in the [PHP Standards Recommendations - i.e. P.S.R.s](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/). Between [PSR-1 Basic Coding Standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/) and [PSR-12: Extended Coding Style](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) many common conventions for idiomatic PHP are outlined. In the original code the first couple lines have spaces around the binary operator `=`:

> ```
>  $splitted_hash = str_split(strtolower(substr($hash, 0, 5)));
>  $path = "";
> ```

there are no spaces around the operator `.=` within the loop:

> ```
> foreach($splitted_hash as $char) {
>       $path.="/$char";
> }
> ```

Adding a space before and after the assignment operator, as well as keywords like `foreach`, is a common convention for readability.

```
foreach ($splitted_hash as $char) {
    $path .= "/$char";
}
```

## Simpler approaches to adding slashes

One could use regular expressions to replace each character with the slash followed by the character. The sample below uses [`preg_replace()`](https://php.net/preg_replace) to match any character that is not a white space character - with [the Generic character type](https://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcrepattern.html#genericchartypes) `\S`.

```
function create_path($hash)
{
    return preg_replace('#\S#u', '/$0', strtolower(substr($hash, 0, 5))) .'/';
}
```

[online demo](https://3v4l.org/c3H1H)

Other generic character types could be used - e.g. `\w` for any word character - in general i.e. A-Z, a-z, 0-9 and `_`, though it can vary depending on the locale:

> A "word" character is an underscore or any character that is a letter or digit. By default, the definition of letters and digits is controlled by PCRE's low-valued character tables, and may vary if locale-specific matching is taking place (see ["Locale support"](https://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcreapi.html#localesupport) in the [**pcreapi**](https://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcreapi.html) page). For example, in a French locale such as "fr_FR" in Unix-like systems, or "french" in Windows, some character codes greater than 127 are used for accented letters, and these are then matched by \w. The use of locales with Unicode is discouraged. <sup>[1](https://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcrepattern.html#genericchartypes)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

To win the prize for ugliest pattern, you can match individual alphanumeric characters with `\w` (which also technically matches underscores) then forget them with `\K` so that you don't need to mention them as a backreference in the replacement string.

Later in the same pattern if there are 5 characters before the current position, you can match the remainder of the string and replace it with a slash.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Y9JON))

```
function create_path(string $hash): string
{
    return preg_replace('#\w\K((?<=\w{5}).+)?#', '/', strtolower($hash));
}

echo create_path('aHq6dc93d7b');
// will output "a/h/q/6/d/"
```

---

If you want to make one more step away from professional looking code, you can access each character by its offset.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/tD9Ne))

```
function create_path(string $hash): string
{
    return strtolower("{$hash[0]}/{$hash[1]}/{$hash[2]}/{$hash[3]}/{$hash[4]}/");
}

echo create_path('aHq6dc93d7b');
// will output "a/h/q/6/d/"
```

Comment: As a code pessimisation this is amazing...

Comment: @2e0byo you mean the above is faster? I just checked it on 50,000,000  loop and it did it in 6 seconds, whereas the join did it in 13 seconds, so that's pretty amazing indeed

Comment: I meant it's unreadable!  If this is really a bottleneck, maybe, but I struggle to believe it could be...

Answer (score 2):

If performance is a goal, and the number of subdirectories is always the same, why don't you simply do that :

```
function create_path($hash)
{
  return "$hash[0]/$hash[1]/$hash[2]/$hash[3]/$hash[4]";
}
```

I made a benchmark on 10,000,000 function call, your code gives this :

real    0m4.059s

user    0m4.016s

sys     0m0.047s

The former gives this :
real    0m1.204s
user    0m1.172s
sys     0m0.016s

After a few runs of each solution.

Comment: That's nice, and I just realized also @mickmackusa did something similar. I just tested it in a loop of 50,000,000 times and it did it in 6 seconds, whereas the other answer with join did it in 13 seconds, that's amazing. It looks so simple that it's unthinkable of :D, I'm probably going to use this one!

Comment: "_did something similar_"?  Um, this is a benchmark on one of the snippets in my review with the `strtolower()` call removed.  We kinda want reviewers to at least _look_ at the previously posted reviews to avoid posting redundant advice.  This answer could have been a comment under my answer.

Comment: Oops sorry for this one i'm new and didn't check all your answers. My bad.